# upstart job for sidekiq not working

Tags: 14.04, upstart

Below is the upstart script for sidekiq.
Running upstart

```
sudo service sidekiq start
```

Gets the following error

```
sidekiq: unrecognized service
```

Following is the `sidekiq.conf` content

```
# Just a custom description for our Job
description "Sidekiq Background Worker"

# On which conditions the job should start. In this case it's very simple: On the system startup (this is basically when the system is booted)
#start on startup
start on runlevel [2345]

# On which conditions the job should stop. In this case when the system reboot (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels)
stop on runlevel [06]

# This are the User and User Group that will be used to run the Job. On our case it should be the user that we have set on our capistrano script for instance.
# You can check at `config/deploy/<environment>.rb` on this line `server <some_ip_addreess>, user: <deploy_user>`

setuid ubuntu
setgid ubuntu

# This indicate that we want to restart the Job if it crashes
respawn
respawn limit 3 30

# TERM is sent by sidekiqctl when stopping sidekiq.  Without declaring these as normal exit codes, it just respawns.
normal exit 0 TERM

script
# this script runs in /bin/sh by default
# respawn as bash so we can source in RVM
exec /bin/bash <<EOT
  # use syslog for logging
  exec &> /dev/kmsg

  # Jump into the capistrano deployment directory
  cd /home/ubuntu/myproject/

  # Start Sidekiq through RVM. Note that I'm using the standard Capistrano paths
  exec ~/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell -c 'bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/sidekiq.yml --environment production --logfile /home/ubuntu/myproject/log/sidekiq.log'

EOT

end script
```

No logs are displayed in `syslog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symlink of your upstart file from /etc/init/sidekiq.conf to /etc/init.d/sidekiq and then run `sudo service sidekiq start` .

A better way to debug your upstart script is to put pre and post block as mentioned here http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html .

Here is a sample sidekiq.conf https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/upstart/sidekiq.conf .

Put the below code in your exec part to send all the output and errors to a file .

```
exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log  # send stderr from this file to a log file
exec 1>&2                      # send stdout to the same log file
set -x
```

Comment: Don't know who down-voted your question. But it worked for me. The problem was that I made the upstart in `init.d`, when I moved it to `/etc/init/`directory, it worked.